# Wigner function for a Lorentzian function

Tags: wavefunction, research-level, normalization, wigner-transform

I am calculating the Wigner function for a Lorentzian function, which is the Fourier transform of the exp(-|*x*|) damping function. But I am having a problem normalizing this function, as I am getting the Sinh Cosh function in the Wigner function for position coordinate. Please guide me on this, that is, how to normalize this Wigner function. My wavefunction is well-behaved (normalizable) in both position and momentum space.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are familiar with the pathologies of the (Lorentz, Breit-Wigner) [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution). But your hyperbolic functions do not seem right.

The basic integral you need is , of course,
$$
\int^\infty_{-\infty} dx \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}=\pi/2 ~.
$$

Your normalized wavefunction should be 
$$
\psi=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{1}{1+x^2}.
$$
 [image: purple curve] (cf. purple curve)

---

The real Wigner function ($\hbar=1$, upon nondimensionalization), ***automatically normalized*** (by virtue of the *p* integral collapse and the normalization of the wave function, above), is then 
$$
f(x,p)= \frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy ~ \frac{e^{iyp}}{(1+(x-y/2)^2)(1+(x+y/2)^2)} .
$$

Before evaluation, recall $f(x,p)=f(-x,p)=f(x,-,p)$, and, by above,  $~f(0,0)=1/\pi$.

$$
f(x,p)= \frac{2}{\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy ~\frac{e^{i2yp}}
{(y-x-i)(y-x+i)(y+x-i)(y+x+i)} ~.
$$
The poles are at $i\pm x, ~ -i\pm x$.

Cauchy's theorem leads to [contour-integrating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_2_.E2.80.93_Cauchy_distribution) in the upper-half complex plane for *p*>0, and the lower one for *p*<0.

For *p*>0,
$$
f=\frac{4i}{\pi} e^{-2p} \left (\frac{e^{i2px}}{8ix(x+i)} 
+ \frac{e^{-i2px}}{8ix(x-i)}\right)
=\frac{e^{-2p}}{\pi(1+x^2)} (\cos (2px) +\sin(2px) /x ).
$$

For *p*<0,
$$
f(x,p)=\frac{e^{2p}}{\pi(1+x^2)} (\cos (2px) -\sin(2px) /x ).
$$

Hence

- Hence, $$
  f(x,p)=\frac{e^{-2|p|}}{\pi(1+x^2)} \left(\cos (2px) +\frac{\sin(2|p|x)} {x} \right),
  $$
  with the requisite symmetries and value at the origin specified in advance.
- In fact,
  $$
  f(0,p)= \frac{e^{-2|p|}}{\pi} (1+2|p|), \qquad f(x,0)= \frac{ 1}{\pi(1+x^2)}~,
  $$
  so the moment pathologies of the Cauchy distribution trail the *p*=0 Wigner function!

---

***Bonus aside on the δ potential*** : Would this look familiar?

Well, if you interchanged *x* with *p*, your Fourier transform $\exp(-|x|)$ is the sole bound state of the attractive [δ potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential), for *κ* = 1; so *f(p,x)* instead of the above would be its Wigner Function!