# Classical motion in delta potential

Tags: classical-mechanics, scattering, dirac-delta-distributions, propagator, regularization

The question about classical motion in delta potential may seem artificial, but it makes sense if you try to calculate the propagator for particle in delta-potential, because you usually need to know classical solutions to pick normalization factor out. We deal with following lagrangian:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = \dfrac{m\dot{q}^2}{2}-\alpha \delta(q - q_0) \implies E =  \dfrac{m\dot{q}^2}{2}+\alpha \delta(q - q_0) = const.
\end{equation}

So we must solve such an equation:

\begin{equation}
\dot{q}^2 = \dfrac{2E}{m}-\dfrac{2 \alpha}{m}\delta(q-q_0).  
\end{equation}

Unfortunately it looks pretty unsolvable, usual separation of variables doesn't work here because of delta function.

I have an idea to represent delta as a limit, like $$\delta(x) = \lim\limits_{a \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{1}{\pi}\dfrac{a}{a^2+x^2},$$ and take this limit after integration, but the integral is elliptic and even Mathematica can't deal with it.

Does this problem have some solution?

Comment: Have you tried the standard trick in QM? solve for $q<q_0$ and $q>q_0$, and match the solutions. Does this work?

Comment: Why don't you exploit a different representation of delta? For instance, as the limit of  finite rectangular potential barriers of equal area but vanishing width? The resulting classical motion is trivial. BTW, this is also the simplest a safest way to introduce delta-like interaction in QM.

Comment: Off chance you could intuit the classical limit of the associated [Wigner function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/319664/wigner-function-for-a-lorentzian-function).

Comment: A particle rolls uniformly on a surface, accelerates when it enters a symmetric depression, and continues past it unaffected. Make the depression deeper and smaller: In the limit, you never see any effect. By contrast, a positive bump in the limit will never be exceeded by *E*, so it will act like a brick wall.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: The classical point particle in 1D will transmit as nothing has happened if $\alpha<0$, and reflect if $\alpha>0$.

As a regularization of the [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) we can use the [triangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) 
$$ \delta_{\epsilon}(x)~=~\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}(\epsilon-|x|)_+ \qquad \Rightarrow\qquad \delta^{\prime}_{\epsilon}(x)~=~-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}{\rm sgn}(x)\theta(|x|-\epsilon).$$
The mechanical energy conservation
$$ E~=~\frac{m}{2}\dot{x}^2 +V(x), \qquad V(x)~=~\alpha\delta(x),\qquad \delta(x)~=~\lim_{\epsilon\searrow 0^+} \delta_{\epsilon}(x), $$
or equivalently, Newton's 2nd law,
$$ m\ddot{x}~=~-V^{\prime}(x), $$
can be solved exactly for the triangular regularization in each of the space regions 
$$]-\infty, -\epsilon] ,\quad [-\epsilon,0],\quad [0,\epsilon],\quad \text{and}\quad [\epsilon,\infty[.$$
Finally, the exact solutions can be glued together by assuming continuity of position & velocity (but not necessarily acceleration!) as a function of time $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the system is time independent and the potential vanishes outside the vicinity of $q=q_0$, the kinetic energy of the system must be conserved. This means that a particle which impacts the potential at time $t'$ must look like
$$q(t)=\begin{cases}~~~v(t-t')+q_0 & t<t'\\ \pm v(t-t') +q_0& t>t' \\ \end{cases}$$
If $\alpha<0$ then the particle is unaffected and we pick the $+$ sign, alternatively the particle is reflected for $\alpha>0$ and we pick the $-$ sign.

I think the best approach to derive this from first principles is to use the representation
$$V(q)=\lim_{a\to0}\begin{cases}0 & |q-q_0|>a/2\\ \alpha/a& |q-q_0|<a/2 \\ \end{cases}$$